# What are the best practices to clone a project from git?

Tags: git, laravel-5, composer-php

Imagine if you have a laravel project in your local computer and you pushed that project to git(github,gitlab,etc..). That project is already equipped with several new libraries while developing in local. Now, if you clone this project in a remote server(say digitalocean or aws), you'll get errors regarding libraries and extensions. For example, ".env" file is avoided by default in ".gitignore". In this case, you'll get some encryption error. So, is it better to clone the entire project and solve the errors one by one? Or is it better to install a new laravel application and libraries and pull only coding part? If so, what is the order?

```
case 1
a. Clone (git and remote server will be linked)
b. Remove project and install fresh laravel application and libraries
c. Pull for coding part

case 2
a. First install fresh laravel application and libraries
b. Now clone or pull coding part from git server
c. Commit changes

I know step b is wrong in both the cases.
```

Can anyone please guide me through this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: case 2 will be ideal for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intended way for Laravel is:

1) Build a project, ignore all libraries because they are tracked somewhere else.
The libraries you need are getting installed with package managers like `[composer][1]` and `[webpack][1]` / `[bower][1]` or whatever you like. The list of required libraries is of course tracked e.g. `composer.json` and `bower.json`

2) To make life easier you can add [composer hooks](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) for minifying you code using Laravel `[mix][2]` or `[gulp][2]` or [whatever you like](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/) for `js` and `css` preprocessing. Or a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

3) If you did everything correctly, when installing your webapp on a new server, all you have to run is `git clone MyProject` (`&& composer update`) and it will run. Of course you need some small configuration, but that is not in the scope of your Laravel code.